# using ui bootstrap tpls directives

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

Here is the deal. I have a problem with using ui-bootstrap-tpls directives namely "pagination". Library is connected successfully in requirejs, you can see in the haed, but directive is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-requiremodule="angularBootstrap" src="/components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js">

<div ng-controller="myController">
    <pagination direction-links="false" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" num-pages="smallnumPages"></pagination>
</div>
```

here is requirejs:

```
    requirejs.config({

    baseUrl: '/',

    paths: {

        'angular': 'components/angular/angular',
        'angularRoute': 'components/angular-route/angular-route',
        'angularBootstrap': 'components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls',

    },
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            deps: [ 'jquery' ],
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angularRoute': {
            deps: [ 'angular' ]
        },
        'angularBootstrap': {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
    }
});
```

and app.js:

```
define(['angular', 'angularBootstrap', 'angularRoute'], function (angular) {

'use strict';

    return angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute']);
});
```

Comment: More code would be useful, especially the app line where you DO inject directives ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app.js should be like this:

```
define(['angular', 'angularBootstrap', 'angularRoute'], function (angular) {

'use strict';

    return angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap']);
});
```

in return angular.module it was necessary to add 'ui.bootstrap'